# Send a wind turbine to space

Tags: energy, power

Would it be viable to send a wind turbine which will be propelled by wind during a lift to space? Will it be able to produce significant amount of electricity while in space?

Comment: This question does not show a good grasp of several basic concepts. The answer is no.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because basic physics see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion

Comment: This is a very weak question.

Answer (score 4):

If you attached a wind turbine to a rocket, it would create drag while in the atmosphere and slow the rocket down.

Once in space, the wind turbine might have energy to use as it will continue to spin, but once you harness the energy it will slow down and eventually stop. Even if you don't directly harness the energy, friction would slow it to a stop. Better to use solar panels.

Comment: You could, on the other hand, use a wind turbine on Jupiter (-;

Comment: nice! good call. how fast are the winds on Jupiter?

Comment: Fast enough to blow everything to pieces.  The second problem is that you would need to anchor it somewhere.

Comment: @gerrit what would you anchor it to?  Energy is harnessed capturing the difference between the speed of the turbine (generally bolted to the ground) and the wind speed.  On Jupiter, how/where would you mount the turbine to harness energy?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Note that I never claimed the problems were easy to solve ;-)